# Is there a hyperbolic variant of the sine-cosine fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series, hyperbolic-functions

The sine-cosine form of the fourier series is given by:

$$ s_{\scriptscriptstyle N}(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \left(a_n \cos\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) + b_n \sin\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) \right) $$

I was wondering if there is something similar for the hyperbolic trigonemetric functions

$$ s_{\scriptscriptstyle N}(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \left(a_n \boxed{\cosh}\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) + b_n \boxed{\sinh}\left(\tfrac{2\pi}{P} nx \right) \right)$$

Seems kind of useless because the hyperbolic functions are not really periodic in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The hyperbolic functions do have imaginary periods (because $\cosh x = \cos(ix)$ and $i\sinh x = \sin(ix)$ for all real $x$), but to write such a series on the real axis analogously to a Fourier series we'd first need an inner product with respect to which the proposed "basic" functions form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Note that the hyperbolic variant of the Fourier transform is the two-sided Laplace transform.